# ¿Qué tengo mal en esta consulta/trigger SQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, trigger

estoy usando MariaDB 10.4.24 en Windows.

Tengo una base de datos, de entre todo hay 2 tablas en específico y 1 procedimiento que me está dando problemas, os describo las tablas:

1. Orders - Registra las compras efectuadas por el usuario
2. OrdersProducts - Registra de la compra efectuada, los productos adquiridos por el usuario

Tengo el siguiente Trigger SQL que antes de insertar en la segunda tabla, comprueba si el stock nuevo es negativo y si lo es si a ese pedido no le corresponden productos, en caso de el stock sea positivo, se desea actualizar. Código:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE quantity integer;
    DECLARE error_msg VARCHAR(255);
SELECT p.prodStock - NEW.quantity INTO quantity FROM products p WHERE p.prodId = NEW.prodId;
SET @ordersize = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ordersproducts WHERE orderId = (
    SELECT orderId FROM orders AS o WHERE 
      DATE_FORMAT(o.orderDate, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') 
      AND o.orderId = NEW.orderId
  )
);
IF quantity < 0 THEN  
  set error_msg = 'La cantidad del stock solicitado supera la cantidad actual';
  IF @ORDERSIZE = 0 THEN
    set error_msg = CONCAT(error_msg, ', ', 'pedido cancelado');
  END IF;
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = error_msg;
ELSE
  UPDATE `products` SET `prodStock`= `prodStock` - NEW.quantity WHERE products.prodId = NEW.prodId;        
END IF;
END
```

Este procedimiento funciona perfectamente si hago una inserción de múltiple de este tipo:

```
INSERT INTO ordersproducts (orderId, prodId, quantity) VALUES (4, 4, 5), (4, 4, 6);
```

Pero qué pasa si se desconoce el identificador del usuario que realizó el pedido o el/los identificadores que tienen los nombres de los productos... Se debe hacer una selección con subconsultas.

Para ello he ideado la siguiente manera (Puede no ser la más eficaz):

```
INSERT INTO ordersproducts (orderId, prodId, quantity) 
  SELECT (SELECT MAX(orderId) FROM orders WHERE userId = 'user1'), 
  (SELECT MAX(prodId) FROM products WHERE prodName = 'test_prod01'), 
  1 
UNION ALL 
  SELECT (SELECT MAX(orderId) FROM orders WHERE userId = 'admin'), 
  (SELECT MAX(prodId) FROM products WHERE prodName = 'test_prod02'), 
  2;
```

El problema es que cuando hago esto, me da esta salida:

**#1442 - Can't update table 'products' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger**

Lo curioso es, cuando elimino el trigger realiza la inserción perfectamente, pero yo quiero que inserte y actualize el stock...

Alguna idea en qué puedo estar fallando?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Vale, estoy investigando, y al parecer creo que lo que está fallando es que el error hace alusion a las subconsultas a la tabla Products, sigo investigando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede porque intentas actualizar una tabla dentro de una función que se está ejecutando como parte de una consulta que también afecta a la misma tabla.

Prueba algo así:

```
-- Definir una variable de usuario para almacenar el prodId
SET @prodId = (SELECT MAX(prodId) FROM products WHERE prodName = 'test_prod01');

-- Insertar los datos en la tabla ordersproducts
INSERT INTO ordersproducts (orderId, prodId, quantity)
  SELECT (SELECT MAX(orderId) FROM orders WHERE userId = 'user1'), @prodId, 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT (SELECT MAX(orderId) FROM orders WHERE userId = 'admin'), 
    (SELECT MAX(prodId) FROM products WHERE prodName = 'test_prod02'), 2;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!, me ha funcionado :)